# Confidence interval for diagnostic test

Tags: statistics

So I've been landed a mini project and I want to check.

I've been asked to work out confidence intervals for a set of results from a new test being conducted. I'm used to finding the mean, sd etc with numerical values but this test is a yes/no or invalid result.

So I end up with
Sample 1 negative
Sample 2 positive
Sample 3 invalid
Sample 4 negative
And so on...

In order to work out the mean, sd etc can I just give each of the three options a number I.e positive 1, negative 0 etc and work it out from there?

Or is there another technique for this type of problem?

I've got total number of positives, negatives and invalids. Just not sure what to do next